# Interval of p in the quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

In what interval does p lie for which both the roots of this equation are less than 2?
Since both the roots are less than 2, their sum should be less than 4; giving 20p/4<4, that is, 5p<4, or, p<4/5. How to find out the minimum value of p?

Comment: What about the product of the roots?

Comment: I am not sure whether the product of the roots should be greater than 4, since the roots can be negative too.

Comment: What you can also do is to solve the equation for "x". This will give you the two roots as functions of parameter "p". Now, plot on the same graph, the variations of each root (the maximum or minimum value of "p" will be defined by the existence of two real roots whatever their sign could be). I wish this be of some help to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first find an expression for the roots, using the Quadratic Formula. There is a fair bit of simplification, and we get
$$x=\frac{5p\pm \sqrt{66-15p}}{2}.$$
The roots are non-real if $p\gt 4.4$. So we look below this value of $p$.

The larger root has the $+$, so we want to solve the inequality 
$$\frac{5p+ \sqrt{66-15p}}{2}\lt 2,$$ or equivalently 
$\sqrt{66-15p}\lt 4-5p$.  Clearly this inequality cannot hold if $4-5p\lt 0$.

As long as $4-5p\ge 0$, that is, as long as $p\lt 0.8$, our inequality  is equivalent to the inequality $25p^2-40p+16\gt 66-15p$.

The roots of $25p^2-25p-50=0$ are $-1$ and $2$.  The big root is greater than $0.8$, so the only possibilities are $p\lt -1$.